# Electronics and electrical projects certification

Tags: embedded, certification, project-management

What certification is required to sell my engineering projects online in India? if I build my project as product to sell online what certification is required for this as well?

Comment: This is really a question about Indian law, not about electronics per se.  You may have better chances asking on a legal stackexchange, if there's one that has much activity on Indian law.  Frankly, I suspect none -- certainly there's no **law** against this sort of thing in the United States, just a healthy risk of getting sued for more than you're worth if you sell a physical product that hurts someone.

Comment: I asked in a law firm they said I've to check in electronics Fourm. So I'm asking.

Comment: It's fine to ask what _technical_ directives/standards a product must fulfil to be put on a certain market. However, in order to answer such questions we will need to know more of the product. Does it contain radio communication, batteries, high voltages and so on. If your question is about technical requirements and 3rd party testing etc it _is_ on-topic here, but as it currently stands, it's too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're selling a project you're fine. Unless maybe people lives are involved there aren't regulations or law that your project must fullfil.

If you're selling an electronic product things are different. Your product has to be compliant to safety and EMC regulations.

Comment: Is there a way I can find more information. Let's assume I built automatic pump controller project and want to sell as project in this case no certification is necessary? And I upgraded that project to product. Though the application is same for the second case should I need any certification?

Comment: Finished products have to be certified. Projects, first prototypes of a product, samples are not required to be certified.